# Styling TextBox cursor/caret

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I've been looking around for a while, and have not come across a way to do this. I need to be able to change the height and width of a `TextBox` **caret**, is this possible? I understand that I can change the brush via `CaretBrush`, but have not yet found a way for the size.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Without trying, I'm just taking a shot in the dark... will changing the font size of the textbox work?

Comment: No, I've changed the font size and it appears to be the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with a solution using XAML and some code behind. You can find the article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633935/Customizing-the-Caret-of-a-WPF-TextBox).